# How to Install QGIS Server on Debian Stretch

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS version 3.4. I have downloaded training manual of same version. right now I am try to complete 12 chapter i.e., install QGIS server. Here I dnt understand where to give command or expression. [image]

Comment: It seems you are trying to install it on windows, the commands are for linux operating systems. You need to use a virtual machine/linux computer. Are you sure you need QGIS Server or are you just going through the training manual? if you don't need the server then skip ahead to a QGIS Desktop chapter.